# Why is pandas trying to convert the header of the column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I need to convert this column of the data frame from type 'object' to type 'int'. Also I've noticed that the column contains strings. I've done this before many times in other projects but now for some reason it wants to convert the header of the column 'age' too??? I've looked everywhere and I cannot figure out why it is trying to do this. There is a link to a website describing the dataframe in a comment in the code.

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Oct 14 08:55:32 2023

@author: Josep
"""

import pandas as pd

#The names of the columns as specified by: 
#https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.names
column_names=['age','workclass',
              'fnlwgt','education',
              'education-num','marital-status',
              'occupation','relationship',
              'race','sex',
              'capital-gain','capital-loss',
              'hours-per-week','native-country']

adult_income=pd.read_csv('adult_income_dataset_org.csv', names=column_names, na_values='?')
adult_income.reset_index

#Number of rows and columns in dataset.
rows=adult_income.shape[0]
columns=adult_income.shape[1]
print(f'adult_income shape:\n{rows} rows\n{columns} columns',end='\n\n')

#Checking for missing values in dataset and which have the most
null_values=adult_income.isnull().sum()
null_values=null_values.sort_values(ascending=False)
print(f'Missing values:\n{null_values}',end='\n\n')


#Which column has the most missing values.
print(f'The column with the most missing values is {null_values.index[0]} with {null_values.values[0]}.',
      end='\n\n')

#Datatypes of each column.
print(f'Datatypes of each column using .dtype:\n{adult_income.dtypes}',end='\n\n')
#I found out that dtypes in this case is incorrect.
print(f'Datatypes of each column using type() instead')
for col in adult_income.columns:
    print(f'{col}:{type(col)}')
print('They are all actually strings!',end='\n\n')

#Before converting, we need to get rid of nulls otherwise we will recieve an error.
adult_income.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
adult_income.reset_index()
#Correcting incorrect types in columns.

adult_income['age']=adult_income['age'].astype(int)
```

I get this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'age'

[First two columns of csv file before I edit it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRFZF.png)

I've tried using .to_numeric(), .astype(int). I've tried a function which only converts strings to integers and that went well before it got stuck on a string of 21 for whatever reason.

Comment: what does `adulte_income.age.dtype` returns? It could be the case that you have strings (words) in that column.

Comment: Hey, you are my very first reply on Stack Exchange thx! '''adult_income.age.dtype''' gives dtype('O'). Using '''adult_income.dtypes''' gives 'object' for 'age'. Also I used a for loop which cycled through all the columns (col for column) and used type()    
'''for col in adult_income.columns:
    print(f'{col}:{type(col)}')'''                                                                                               That gave me <class 'str'>. So in short yes it does contain strings but I still don't see why it cannot convert???

Comment: you can convert numbers which are of type string to number i.e. `int('12')` would work, but if you have alphabets, it won't work i.e. `int('a')` would not work. Try `int('a')` and you will get the same error as above. Try this: create a new column: `df['check'] = pd.to_numeric(df['your_col'], errors='coerce')`, this will replace rows which were throwing errors with `NA`. Then you can see those rows by using `df[df['check'].isna()]`

Comment: I found 3 NA values after doing this! I I'm still not sure how they were created but I got things working now. Just needed to move the dropna() to after to_numeric. Thank you!

Comment: those three NA values represent invalid numbers, i.e. those rows contains some invalid character like alphabets